# Does putting an automatic car in neutral when stopped help save petrol?

Tags: transport, cars, fuel-efficiency

In Australia, most cars are automatic, and most people stay on "drive" while braking when stopped at a red light (i.e. if they weren't breaking, the car would drive forward).

I was wondering if moving the gear handle to "neutral" when stopping for a couple of minutes would help save a non-negligeable amount of petrol?

I am aware of the following existing question but I consider my question to be different enough to ask it:
[When does using a car's start-stop system become more economical?](https://sustainability.stackexchange.com/questions/1253/when-does-using-a-cars-start-stop-system-become-more-economical)

Comment: If it also prevents wear on the transmission, it could save money on that too.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to [this answer over on mechanics.SE](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/a/3904), below a certain engine RPM, your vehicle automatically disengages the torque converter. That is to say, when stopped, there isn't a fundamental difference between having the transmission in drive or neutral.

On the other hand, shifting back and forth each time you're at a stop light does cause a bit of wear, and slows your reaction time (meaning you might slow traffic behind you, or be unable to respond quickly in case of emergency).